# Meaning of function coverage in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Here is the output from running `jest` on one of my components:

```
----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                   |     100 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
 search-suggestion-base.tsx |     100 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
----------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
...
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for functions (100%) not met: 50%
```

Note that `% Funcs` is not 100 and the test fails. (The coverage threshold is not set by me. I wouldn't have set such a high threshold.)

The problem is, Jest is not telling me which are the uncovered lines. Besides, I'm also having trouble figuring out what's the meaning of `% Funcs`. I can't even find the official documentation for this `% Funcs`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you open `.coverage/lcov-report/index.html` in the browser to check if there are uncovered lines? About how to read the coverage reporter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618243/how-do-i-read-an-istanbul-coverage-report

Comment: @slideshowp2 Thanks a lot! The report does show the  uncovered lines!

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @slideshowp2, `.coverage/lcov-report/index.html` does show the uncovered lines.

The `.coverage` folder didn't exist at fist. I had to ran `jest` with the `--coverage` parameter. You can refer to [How to get the code coverage report using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825860/how-to-get-the-code-coverage-report-using-jest) for more information.

By the way, it turned out that a default event handler - which is a function - was not covered. So I guess `% Funcs` means literally the percentage of functions covered.

In my case, the default event handler is an empty function `() => {}`. I think that's why Jest told me that "statements, branches and lines" are all covered, but "functions" are not.

Comment: can you please mention what should we pass as default value for the functions?